# How to install and use Windows 7 in a Kingston SSDNow V300

Tags: windows-7, boot, installation, ssd

Few days ago I bought a Kingston SSDNow V300 240 GB SSD, and replaced my "old" notebook (ASUS S46C) hybrid disk (750 GB HD + 24 GB SSD).

So, on Windows 7 installation I got 2 disks, first one (disk 0) with 24 GB and other one (disk 1) with 240 GB. I partitioned disk 1 with 100 GB + 140 GB, and installed Windows 7 in the 100 GB partititon.

Everything occurs normally, including the first boot to finish Windows installation. But when I try to restart Windows manually, looks like Windows is not recognized anymore. Boot stops in a blank screen, with a blinking cursor.

I already tried some fix procedures, like boot with Windows DVD > repair installation > Command Prompt >  bootrec /fixMbr | bootrec /fixboot | bootrec /RebuildBcd. I also installed the ASUS ExpressCache application. But problem persists :(

Please, can some expert help me?

Thank you!